# How to solve the following convex optimization problem to get a closed form solution?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Please, can you help to solve the following convex optimization problem to get a closed-form solution?

I tried to solve it using Lagrange multiplier but it's not easy. I can't get the closed-form solution to the value of x and y.

\begin{equation}\label{MINPower}
\min  \; x + y
\end{equation}
subject to
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
C1 &: (\left | a\right | \sqrt{x} + \left | b \right | \sqrt{y} )^2  \geq  c, \\
C2 &:  0 \leq x , y \leq c, \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

My trial

$x+y-\lambda_1 \left | a\right | ^2 x - \lambda_1 \left | b \right |^2 y - 2\lambda_1 \left | a\right | \left | b\right | \sqrt{xy} + \lambda_1 c - \lambda_2 x - \lambda_3 y + \lambda_4 x - \lambda_4 c + \lambda_5 y - \lambda_5 c= 0$

Differentiate with respect to $x$ -- > $ 1 + \lambda_1 \left | a\right | ^2  + \lambda_1 \left | a\right | \left | b\right | \sqrt{y} x^{-1/2}  - \lambda_2  + \lambda_4 = 0$

Differentiate with respect to $y$ -- > $ 1 +\lambda_1 \left | b\right | ^2  + \lambda_1 \left | a\right | \left | b\right | \sqrt{x} y^{-1/2}  - \lambda_3   + \lambda_5 = 0$

$-\lambda_1 \left | a\right | ^2 x - \lambda_1 \left | b \right |^2 y - 2\lambda_1 \left | a\right | \left | b\right | \sqrt{xy} + \lambda_1 c = 0$

$- \lambda_2 x = 0$

$- \lambda_3 y = 0$

$ \lambda_4 x - \lambda_4 c = 0$

$ \lambda_5 y - \lambda_5 c = 0$

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: "$-\lambda_1 c$" should be added, not subtracted, and you cannot just differentiate w.r.t. $\lambda_i$ because $\lambda$ has to be nonnegative (because of this error, the final equations are very easy to solve, so your comment on it being "too complicated" makes it seem you have not looked at the final equations at all)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have revised it. Can you suggest a good reference for handling such kinds of problems with examles?

Comment: Look for the KKT conditions to see how to deal with inequalities.

Comment: you mean I only differentiate with respect to x and y and let all constraints satisfy with equality and try a different combinations of active or inactive constraints?

Comment: I tried again but I still cannot get the closed-form solution. I appreciate if you can help.